# How to calculate Fourier transform on a linear discontinuous function?

Tags: fourier-transform

How to calculate Fourier transform on a linear discontinuous function, like the Haar scaling function $$f(t)=1 \text{ for } 0\leq t<1, \text{ and }0,  \text{ otherwise }$$
Or, a  similar problem of determining the Fourier transform of the function $f$  defined by $f(t) = 1$
if $0 < t \leq 1, $ and $  \:f(t) = -1$ if $-1 < t < 0$ and $f(t) = 0$ otherwise.

I have the solution for a similar function, though this is symmetric, it goes as follows:
$$f(t)=\begin{cases}t+\pi, \quad -\pi \leq t \leq 0,\\
\pi-t, \quad 0 <t \leq \pi,\\
0, \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
It has the fourier transform $$\hat{f}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \cos (\lambda t) dt=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^\infty (\pi-t) \cos (\lambda t) dt $$ this can be solved with integration by parts.

Question can I use the same method on the two first problem

Comment: Can't you just compute them directly from the definition? After all, if $f$ is $+1$ on $[a,b]$ and is $-1$ on $[c,d]$ (and is $0$ everywhere else), then
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)\;dx = \int_a^bg(x)\;dx -\int_c^dg(x)\;dx$$
assuming all of these integrals exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just restrict the range of integration to the range of $t$ where $f(t)$ is non-zero.  You can break the range at points of discontinuity.  So for your second example $$\hat f(\lambda)=\frac 2{\sqrt {2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\cos(\lambda t)dt=\frac 2{\sqrt {2 \pi}}\left(\int_0^1\cos(\lambda t)dt-\int_{-1}^0\cos(\lambda t)dt\right)$$

Comment: Can you restrict it to a particular interval, or does the function have to be  defined on the whole interval

Comment: You can restrict it to the interval where $f$ is non-zero as the integral over the places $f=0$ is zero.

Comment: Then $$\hat{f}=\frac{4\sin(\lambda)}{\sqrt{2\pi} \lambda}$$ in the second case.

Comment: And the first Fourier transform $$\hat{f}(\lambda)=\int_0^1 f(t)\cos(\lambda t) dt=\frac{2\sin(\lambda)}{\sqrt{2\pi} \lambda}$$

Comment: One more question: If i use the $cos(\lambda t)$ instead of using the general formula for Fourier transform $\hat{f}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-i\omega t} dt$, then I loose the complex part of the answer- don't I need them for a complete answer?

Comment: I was following what you did for the Fourier transform.  Yes, you need the sine terms.  In fact since $f$ is odd, the expansion will have only sine terms